# Bootstrap returning no jquery even when there is jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-4

So I'm making an HTML project using jquery bootstrap and jquery easing
when I'm trying the code it returns that

> bootstrap.min.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires
> jQuery. jQuery must be included before Bootstrap's JavaScript.

> jquery.easing.js:17 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

> theme.js:49 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

Even when I am using JQuery in my code.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Main Menu</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="animate.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i,900,900i">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/fonts/fontawesome-all.min.css">
  </head>
  <body id="page-top">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-dark align-items-start sidebar sidebar-dark accordion bg-gradient-primary p-0">
            <div class="container-fluid d-flex flex-column p-0">
                <a class="navbar-brand d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center sidebar-brand m-0" href="#">
                    <div class="sidebar-brand-icon rotate-n-15"><i class="fas fa-laugh-wink"></i></div>
                    <div class="sidebar-brand-text mx-3"><span>Brand</span></div>
                </a>
                <hr class="sidebar-divider my-0">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav text-light" id="accordionSidebar">
                    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation"><a class="nav-link active" href=""><i class="fas fa-tachometer-alt"></i><span>Dashboard</span></a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation"><a class="nav-link" href=""><i class="fas fa-user"></i><span>Profile</span></a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation"><a class="nav-link" href=""><i class="fas fa-table"></i><span>Table</span></a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation"><a class="nav-link" href=""><i class="far fa-user-circle"></i><span>Login</span></a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation"><a class="nav-link" href=""><i class="fas fa-user-circle"></i><span>Register</span></a></li>
                </ul>
                <div class="text-center d-none d-md-inline"><button class="btn rounded-circle border-0" id="sidebarToggle" type="button"></button></div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>

    <script src="jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.4.1/jquery.easing.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/theme.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

What is wrong with this ?

Edit: Found Out That I Need Jquery NPM if im using electron

Comment: check your jquery path seems it not correct  <script src="jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>

Comment: no its in the right place
im just using electron thats what make it error

Comment: so this should help you https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/202/how-to-include-and-use-jquery-in-electron-framework

Answer (score 1):

Check the network tab and make sure the file is loaded. Is the jquery-3.5.1.min.js path correct?